# Is there a way to get a vector with the name of all functions that one could use in R?

Tags: function, r, names

I would like to have a call that returns me a vector with the names of all function that I could call in the current R session. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

(I would like to check user entered variables against this vector. We had some unforseen problem with users entering e.g., `c` as variable names)

**UPDATE:** I would like to get the function names from all packages currently loaded.

**SOLUTION (half way):** Based on Joris Meys tip with `lsf.str()` I came up with the following function that returns a sorted vector with all currently available function names:

```
getFunctionNames <- function() {
    loaded <- (.packages())
    loaded <- paste("package:", loaded, sep ="")
    return(sort(unlist(lapply(loaded, lsf.str))))
}
```

Bu,t see also the comments on Joris Meys' post for even better answers.

Comment: Re your update, I have added a modified version of findfuns() that does exactly that.

Comment: You could just do loaded <- search()[-1] , then you avoid the paste function. Be sure to check whether your return gives a wellformed vector. On my R version I had to nest the as.character within the apply in order to get a clean list of function names instead of a lot of garbled text with the function names hidden in there somewhere. See also my edit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd use `lsf.str()` as a start.

eg : `x <- as.character(lsf.str("package:base"))` gives you a list of all functions in the base package. You could do add all packages you want to check against. `stats` and `utils` come to mind first.

EDIT : Regarding your question about currently loaded packages :

<s>x <- unlist(sapply(search()[-1],function(x)as.character(lsf.str(x))))</s> *see comments*

```
pkgs <- search()
pkgs <- pkgs[grep("package:",pkgs)]
y <- unlist(sapply(pkgs,lsf.str))
```

does the trick.

Comment: I have the impression, the `as.character` part is not needed. So: `y <- unlist(sapply(search()[-1],lsf.str))` also does the trick.

Comment: @Joris: Be aware that other things could be on the search path (attached objects [eughh yuck!]), possibly environments(?)) so it is perhaps better to just use the ones with `"package:"` in them.

Comment: @Gavin : Thx! I was a bit too quick. Hence the `grep` in your solution. Luckily `lsf.str` only lists functions, so it shouldn't cause too many trouble.

Comment: or all in one line: `unlist(lapply(grep("package:",search(),value=TRUE),lsf.str))`. However, you don't search the global environment with this. So, I will stick with the `search()[-1]` version.

Comment: @Henrik: if you want to search the global environment, just use `search()`. `search()[-1]` is everything except the global environment

Answer (score 8):

I asked a similar Q on R-Help many moons ago (2007) and Prof. Brian Ripley provided this as a solution:

```
findfuns <- function(x) {
     if(require(x, character.only=TRUE)) {
        env <- paste("package", x, sep=":")
        nm <- ls(env, all=TRUE)
        nm[unlist(lapply(nm, function(n) exists(n, where=env,
                                               mode="function",
                                               inherits=FALSE)))]
     } else character(0)
}
pkgs <- dir(.Library)
z <-  lapply(pkgs, findfuns)
names(z) <- pkgs
Z <- sort(unique(unlist(z)))
```

Which gives output like:

```
> head(Z)
[1] "^"        "-"        "-.Date"   "-.POSIXt" ":"        "::"
```

This was for finding all the functions in packages specified by object `pkgs` so you can control which packages are loaded/checked against.

A modified version that work on the currently loaded set of packages would be:

```
findfuns2 <- function(pkgs) {
    nm <- ls(pkgs, all = TRUE)
    nm[unlist(lapply(nm, function(n) exists(n, where = pkgs,
                                            mode = "function",
                                            inherits = FALSE)))]
    if(isTRUE(all.equal(length(nm), 0)))
        character(0)
    else
        nm
}

pkgs <- search()
pkgs <- pkgs[grep("package:", pkgs)]
z <- lapply(pkgs, findfuns2)
z <- sort(unique(unlist(z)))
head(z)
```

Comment: @Joris - Nothing, except I didn't know it existed :-)

Comment: @Joris: Just look at `ls.str` - it is basically doing what Brian's `findfuns()` and my modified version do. Guess it didn't exist in 2007.

Comment: @Gavin: I realized. Sorry if I came off harsh, I was just wondering why you didn't use it as you're still way ahead of me in R-experience.

Comment: @Joris - old school :-) (and you didn't come off harsh, at all.) I learned something from your answer. It's nice how R is evolving like this; `lsf.str()` is so similar to Brian's code that that function was added to R follwing the discussions surround my post to R-Help and others' work on getting syntax highlighting and other things working for R.

Comment: @Gavin: Funny, lsf.str() is mentioned on the mailing list as early as 2003, so Prof. Ripley got me puzzled there...

Comment: @Gavin: Even more funny, it was prof. Ripley himself who gave the lsf.str() answer in this mail : http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg03618.html

Comment: @Joris - So Brian must have used the `lsf.str()` code in his example - my original Q was about getting all functions in all stated packages, hence it needed to load in the packages you wanted to search through. Thanks for digging in the archives, Joris!