# Get the list of functions loaded in R's global environment

Tags: function, r, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get a vector with the name of all functions that one could use in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267744/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-vector-with-the-name-of-all-functions-that-one-could-use)

Hi

I would like to get from R the list of functions loaded in the environment.
I know `ls()` that gives the list of objects loaded. But some objects are not functions.
I would like to clean my env from the functions but not from the other objects (matrices, array etc) that contain some of my result that dont want to lose.

Any idea?

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/4267744/429846 ?

Comment: no, stackoverflow.com/q/4267744/429846 is for functions that come from packages, I am talking about functions in ls()

Comment: I didn't notice, but yes, it is a duplicate. Ever tried the solutions given there? Heck, I just realized I even gave exactly the same answer.

Comment: The solution @Joris supplied in that answer is the same as that supplied below. That Q was about all functions that could be called, but if you read `?lsf.str` you'd see how to restrict just to the global environment, and that is the default.

Comment: well ok guys. Indeed the solution is the same. But the question was different. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See `?lsf.str`

```
X <- lsf.str()
as.vector(X) # just for printing purposes, you can use the vector in rm()
rm(list=X)
```

Comment: @G. Grothendieck : or combine everything as `rm(list=lsf.str())`

Answer (score 2):

ok, I have a proposal

```
rm(list=ls()[sapply(ls(), function(obj) "function"==class(eval(parse(text = obj)))[1])])
```

I am sure there is something more elegant.