# Exporting all functions in a workspace to an R source file

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to write all the functions I have in an R workspace to an R file that I can put in a package?

Best wishes,
Ankur.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a vector with the name of all functions that one could use in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267744/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-vector-with-the-name-of-all-functions-that-one-could-use)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I don't need the names of the functions, I need the code of the functions written to a .R file that I can then include in a package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with `lsf.str` (found in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267744/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-vector-with-the-name-of-all-functions-that-one-could-use) of the comment from @hrbrmstr) :

```
dump(list = lsf.str(), file = "functions.R")
```

It write all your function in an R script.

And you can source these functions with :

```
source("functions.R")
```