# Make sure that R functions don't use global variables

Tags: r, function, workspace

I'm writing some code in R and have around 600 lines of functions right now and want to know if there is an easy way to check, if any of my functions is using global variables (which I DON'T want).

For example it could give me an error if sourcing this code:

```
example_fun<-function(x){
  y=x*c
  return(y)
}

x=2
c=2
y=example_fun(x)

WARNING: Variable c is accessed from global workspace!
```

## **Solution to the problem with the help of @Hugh:**

```
install.packages("codetools")
library("codetools")

x = as.character(lsf.str())

which_global=list()

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  which_global[[x[i]]] = codetools::findGlobals(get(x[i]), merge = FALSE)$variables
}
```

### **Results will look like this:**

```
> which_global
$arrange_vars
character(0)

$cal_flood_curve
[1] "..count.." "FI"        "FI_new"   

$create_Flood_CuRve
[1] "y"

$dens_GEV
character(0)
...
```

Comment: The best way is to add `c`in function argument.

Comment: I don't believe what you are asking is possible, it would need to change `R` scoping rules, and that would be a different language or at least a derivative of `R`.

Comment: @Flo.P
Yes I know, but I want to know if there is a way that R/R-Studio can detect that by themself without manual scanning my whole code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given function like `example_function`, you can use package `codetools`:

```
codetools::findGlobals(example_fun, merge = FALSE)$variables
#> [1] "c"
```

To collect all functions see [Is there a way to get a vector with the name of all functions that one could use in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267744/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-vector-with-the-name-of-all-functions-that-one-could-use)

Comment: This was a good starting point and I found a solution to my Problem. I edited it into my post.

Answer (score -1):

What about emptying your global environment and running the function? If an object from the global environment were to be used in the function, you would get an error, e.g.

```
V <- 100
my.fct <- function(x){return(x*V)}
> my.fct(1)
[1] 100
#### clearing global environment & re-running my.fct <- function... ####
> my.fct(1)
Error in my.fct(1) : object 'V' not found
```