# display a list of R functions, so you don't steal an already used name

Tags: r

What's the command to display a list of all functions in R (baring in mind the packages you have installed)? I want to write a function called `new_function` and I want to make sure the name is not in use already. I thought it was `ls()` or `ls(function)` but these don't work.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267744/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-vector-with-the-name-of-all-functions-that-one-could-use) helps

Comment: maybe just `?new_function_name` is the easiest way to do it and then see if anything comes up. Seems easier than @akrun solution although I do appreciate this comment by akrun.